# Virtualhostname is not prepended to routes with Passenger 2.2.2 and Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Before the switch and in all apps on this passenger that run rails 2.0
my routes would yield "myapp/controller/action"

Now they yield "controller/action". Interestingly the `stylesheet_link_tags` do work as normal.

I prepend a prefix in the production environment to deal with this but it is a hideous hack of course.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Passenger 2.2.3 fixed this it is probably not such a big deal anymore but just for the sake of completeness, I post the answer, as I found it out today.

All one has to do is paste this into environment.rb

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/myapp"
```

The problem was connected with how rails handles Sub-URI deplopyments, this was changed in version 2.2 apparently and broke my code.